# Python loop, creating the data frames with the name of the iterator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

So, I'm currently working with a dataframe where each row represents a country, and each column is an indicator (of which there are several), over the years. Imagine hid_1990, hdi_1991, and so forth. There are a lot of indicators, and their names can be quite similar sometimes.

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
ISO3               country    hdicode  ... mf_2019  mf_2020  mf_2021
0  AFG           Afghanistan        Low  ...    1.38     1.38     1.38
1  AGO                Angola     Medium  ...    2.18     2.18     2.18
2  ALB               Albania       High  ...   12.96    12.96    12.96
3  AND               Andorra  Very High  ...     NaN      NaN      NaN
4  ARE  United Arab Emirates  Very High  ...   68.95    68.95    68.95
```

Now, I want only certain indicators, particularly these:

`indexes = ['hdi','ihdi','gnipc','le']`

My objective is to create a dataframe with the name of which indicator, where the only columns that exist are the county code and the corresponding indicator_year.

So, I wan a dataframe called hdi_df, with a column ISO3 (country code), and columns: hdi_1990, hdi_1991 , so forth.

So far I have written this:

```
indexes = ['hdi','ihdi','gnipc','le']   


for ind in indexes:                                                                                
    ind_pattern = rf'{ind}_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'                                                   
    print(ind_pattern)                                                                             
    ind_col = [col for col in several_indicators.columns if re.match(ind_pattern, col.lower())]    
    ind_col.append('ISO3')                                                                         
    ind = several_indicators[ind_col]
```

So my objective was that "ind" would be replaced with the name in the list... but that's not how it happens, it just re-writes on top of it. (I guess I'm used to STATA).

Any solution or recommendation?

Comment: You have used the same name `ind` for two different things, one controlling the for loop and the other being assigned to within it.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample small dataframe and expected output?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables), and the answer to that is usually “don’t do that; use a dictionary instead”.

Comment: I see what you mean, but then how would you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A option could be create dataframe dynamically using `exec`.

```
exec(f'{ind} = several_indicators[ind_col]')
```

Comment: From what I see online using exec() should be avoided?